# How to center text using "turtle" module in Python

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

How can I draw "turtle" text starting from the center of a window? I know how to create "turtle" text, but I don't know how to center the text so it appears from the center of a window.

```
turtle.write("I AM HERE", font=("Arial", 50, "bold"))
```

Thanks for your help,

Howard

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.write): have you tried adding `align="center"` as an argument?

Answer (score 3):

To center text on a point (e.g. the origin at [0, 0]), in the X dimension, you can use the `align=center` keyword argument to `turtle.write()`.  To get alignment in the Y dimension, you need to adjust slightly for the font size:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT_SIZE = 50

FONT = ("Arial", FONT_SIZE, "bold")

yertle = Turtle()

# The turtle starts life in the center of the window
# but let's assume we've been drawing other things
# and now need to return to the center of the window

yertle.penup()
yertle.home()

# By default, the text prints too high unless we roughly
# readjust the baseline, you can confirm text placement
# by doing yertle.dot() after yertle.home() to see center

yertle.sety(-FONT_SIZE/2)

yertle.write("I AM HERE", align="center", font=FONT)

yertle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

However if you instead want to start printing from the center (your post isn't clear), you can change `align=center` to `align=left`, or just leave out the `align` keyword argument altogether.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

> turtle.write(arg, move=False, align="left", font=("Arial", 8,
> "normal"))

Parameters:

> **arg** – object to be written to the TurtleScreen
>
> **move** – True/False
>
> **align** – one of the strings “left”, “center” or right”
>
> **font** – a triple (fontname, fontsize, fonttype)